# My python program sorts information incorrectly

Tags: python

I have no idea how to fix this sorter part. Could anyone help me out here? My program sorter should output something like shown in the image:

[image: 1]

It takes data from the url given and calculates the area of it. But it should also sort the information but it doesn't right now.

```
import json
import urllib.request
import requests
f = open('katastritunnused.txt', 'r')
response = requests.get('https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=41201:004:0067&out=json')
json_response = response.json()
print(json_response["1"].get("Pindala"))
```

This gets and calculates the area of the info got form the url.

```
c = []
list2 = []
def bubblesort(c):
    n = len(c)

    for _ in range(n):
        jarjestatud = True


        for x in range(n - _ - 1):

            if c[x][1] > c[x + 1][1]:   
                c[x][1], c[x + 1][1] = c[x + 1][1], c[x][1]
                jarjestatud = False


        if jarjestatud:
            break

    return c
list2 = []
for j, _ in enumerate(c):
    templist = [_, list2[j]]
    list2.append(templist)
desclist = bubblesort(list2)
desclist.reverse()
def writer(a):
    with open('sorteeritud.csv', mode = 'w',) as csv:
        for b in a:
            csv.write(str(b[0]) +';' + str(b[1])+'\n')
writer(desclist)

f.close()
```

Comment: Why do you write your own sort? Use a standard one

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind by that? Sorry im fairly new

Comment: instead of calling `bubblesort(list2)`, you can use quick sort provided by Python itself: `sorted(list2, key=lambda entry: entry[1])`